# Windows Curses Adding Weird Spacing

Tags: python, windows, terminal, curses

I have some python code that uses curses to continuously print "Test Bot." And allowing me to send messages at the same time now its printing "Test Bot." fine but when I try to enter "Test User." there is some weird spacing before it
Here's the code:

```py
import curses, threading, time
def print_hello(chat_win):
    while True:
        chat_win.addstr("Test Bot.\n")
        chat_win.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.5)
def chat_app():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    curses.curs_set(0)
    chat_win = curses.newwin(curses.LINES - 2, curses.COLS, 0, 0)
    chat_win.scrollok(True)
    input_win = curses.newwin(1, curses.COLS, curses.LINES - 1, 0)
    input_win.addstr("Enter Message: ")
    input_win.refresh()
    hello_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_hello, args=(chat_win,))
    hello_thread.daemon = True
    hello_thread.start()
    while True:
        key = input_win.getch()
        if key == key == 10:
            message = input_win.instr(0, 14).decode()
            chat_win.addstr(message + "\n")
            input_win.clear()
            input_win.addstr("Enter Message: ")
        else:
            input_win.addch(key)
        input_win.refresh()
        chat_win.refresh()
chat_app()
```

now here is what happens when I run it and try to input "Test User.":

```py
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Test Bot. 
 Test User.                                                                                                                                                        
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.                                                                                                                                                         
Test Bot.





                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Enter Message:
```

Now I do not understand at all why this is happening.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your question is closed as a duplicate, then a good thing has happened: you get an answer that helps you, and less duplicate material is created on the internet. If you believe that this is _not_ a duplicate, then explain why in the comments (cc @Thomas) or add an addendum to the question to address this point.

Comment: Your question was closed by a gold-badge holder (for Python), and they are highly likely to be a subject matter expert in that topic. It is usually the case that gold badge closes are correct, even if the question author can't see _why_ the questions are essentially the same. But, mistakes happen, and closed questions can be reopened - just take the above steps if that is the case here.

Comment: The question that this is marked as a duplicate of is about ncurses, not the Python curses package. I an not sure if that multithreading issue is necessarily relevant to this question.

Comment: I think you can cc @ThomasDickey here, assuming you believe the closure signpost is incorrect.

Comment: See above @user11171 ^

Comment: That "windows" tag could be Windows - or not.  Either way, the curses library under the Python **binding** is not thread-safe.

Comment: The question is only tangentially about multi-threading, and that other question is quite clearly about an entirely different topic. It seems like it could be reframed slightly and it wouldn't be a duplicate at all. If the hello_thread is deleted then it still has that issue with the extra space in the output which is answered below.

Comment: The example is printing to the screen using curses in two threads, which is why it produces unexpected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the last space of the "Enter Message: " string. You should shift the x coordinate of the instr method by one more character:

```
message = input_win.instr(0, 15).decode()
```

Comment: But it's better to put the prompt string into a variable:
  `message = input_win.instr(0, len(prompt)).decode()
  ...
  input_win.addstr(prompt)`